# Application force closes on button click

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app has given me 5 different errors on the market and i can't figure it out. It force closes on button click.

This is the first error i was getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.yes.hotrod.main$1.onClick(main.java:25)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my main.java

```
package com.yes.hotrod;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class main extends Activity {MediaPlayer FilmSound;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.animalkingdom);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.animalkingdom);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.animalkingdom); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }});


    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bigassstunt);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bigassstunt);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bigassstunt); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.godsofwar);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.godsofwar);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.godsofwar); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.greentea);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.greentea);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.greentea); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.havefun);
    button11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.havefun);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.havefun); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kisswashot);
    button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kisswashot);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kisswashot); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ohshit);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ohshit);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ohshit); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.throwingstar);
    button8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.throwingstar);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.throwingstar); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.twolegittwoquit);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.twolegittwoquit);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.twolegittwoquit); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.whiskey);
    button10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.whiskey);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.whiskey); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.demons);
    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) 
    {
    FilmSound.stop();
    FilmSound.reset();
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.demons);
    FilmSound.start();
    }
    else {
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.demons); 
    FilmSound.start(); }    
    }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace you will see that the error is occurring on line 25 of main.java, inside the onClick method for the OnClickListener for button1.

Most likely something went wrong when you were trying to instantiate the FilmSound object and it is null inside that method.

Comment: i just can't figure out why i'm getting a force close on a button click.

Comment: Try to separate the parameters of `MediaPlayer.create` and see which one gives you null (if any)